# Property 'myForm' does not exist on type 'ShoppingCartComponent'

Tags: angular

I have the following component html:

```html
<form *ngFor="let product of products" [formGroup]="myForm" name="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit([product.name], [product.price], int)">
    <div id="cartItemsList">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div name="product_name">{{product.name }}</div>
                <div><img src="../assets/images/gallery/{{product.thumbnail}}" /></div>
                <div>{{product.price }}</div>
                <button class="minus-btn" (click)="minus()" type="button" name="minus_btn">
                    <img src="../assets/images/minus.svg" alt="minus" />
                </button>
                <input pattern="^(0|\+?[1-9]\d*)$" class="num" name="int" [value]="int" formControlName="int" ng-minlength="0" type="number">
                <button class="plus-btn" (click)="plus()" type="button" name="plus_btn">
                    <img src="../assets/images/plus.svg" alt="plus" />
                </button>
                <button type="submit" class="btnAddAction">Add to Cart</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.myForm = new FormGroup({
       int: new FormControl()
   });  
}
```

I get the following error:

ERROR in src/app/shopping-cart/shopping-cart.component.ts:80:9 - error TS2339: Property 'myForm' does not exist on type 'ShoppingCartComponent'.

```
80    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
```

but as you can see, myForm does exist in the component. How can I fix this error?

Comment: You need to initialize  ```myForm : FormGroup``` in ts file before ```ngOnInit```.. Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-y69qbj

Comment: I disagree with @Maniraj Murugan,  you can initialize your `FormGroup` within `ngOnInit`, in addition the issue is that the property is not initialized rather that is not exist. would you please modify your post to include your entire component in question?

Comment: @RafiHenig, I mean to say of declaring ```myForm``` with its type as ```FormGroup``` like ```myForm : FormGroup``` .. If this was not done then it will throw the above error..

Comment: can you post your entire shopping-cart.component.ts here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing entire component will help us to solve it in seconds, its ok, have you imported formgroup correctly, as there is a error at line 80, ts env didnt take myForm as variable yet